# While creating Sitecore package getting "System.IO.IOException: The file exists error" in Sitecore 7.2

Tags: sitecore-client

System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()

Comment: check you have this folder + IIS has access to this folder '<instancedir>\Website\temp'

Comment: Can you provide a full stacktrace please? Have you created packages before? Is this a clean instance? What else can you tell us about this error?

Comment: Likely answered here: http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2008/12/sitecore-packager-throwing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error looks like not Sitecore related, and related to your server configuration.

(Sitecore calls system method `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()` with no params and receives the error)

Please check what is the `%TEMP%` variable defined on your machine.
It may be that it looks for a location that does not exist or that the IIS AppPool user do not have read/write permissions for that folder.

You can check the `%TEMP%` variable value using the following method inside the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\vlad>cd %TEMP%


C:\Users\vlad\AppData\Local\Temp>
```

If that folder (result of request on your side) is existent – check if the AppPool user has the appropriate access rights.

Comment: Clearing temp and providing Network user full access to windows folder solved this problem for me.